# How do we create a plain controller in Laravel 8.1 ( --plain does not exist in the new version)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I can no longer use the following syntax to create a plain controller in laravel 8.1

```
$php artisan make:Controller UserController --plain
```

When I execute above command, it fails with:

```
The `--plain` option does not exist
```

Many tutorial still uses the above syntax, what is the new method to generate a plain controller.

Comment: `--plain` doesn't exist. What you're trying to achieve? you can see all possible option by `php artisan make:Controller --help`

Comment: im trying to create a controller

Comment: `$php artisan make:Controller UserController` this is enough to create a controller

Comment: but my tutorial example add --plain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before, **Laravel 5.2** `--plain` was used to make a simple controller without builtin routes and methods. Now :

```
php artisan make:controller UserController
```

Works the same as `--plain`.

You can see all possible option by :

```
php artisan make:Controller --help
```

See the official documentation of **[Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers)**

Comment: my tutorial used version 5 and i used 8.1 so that make sense,thankyou